# How to ignore spec files and mock files in production build in Angular 6

Tags: angular, testing

I m trying to compile in production my angular application and I m receiving this error:

> Cannot determine the module for class TranslateMockPipe in
>   /src/testing/translate.service.spec.ts! Add TranslateMockPipe to the
>   NgModule to fix it.

this `TranslateMockPipe` class is a common class that I declared and I m using it in all my test files in order to avoid repeating the same line of code in all the test cases

the code of the class:

```
@Pipe({ name: "translate" })
class TranslateMockPipe {
    transform = (ss) => ss
}
```

I m using it in my test like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                DemoComponent,
                TranslateMockPipe
            ]
})
```

If I run the project everything goes well, and my test pass without issues but fail when I try to compile for production

How I can ignore this kind of fake classes  for production build?

Comment: the build compile(you running ng build --prod?) does not include test files, that message is probably you are not including the Pipe properly, can you update your question with the module it's included in

Comment: thats the thing mock components and pipes should not be included in any module, is just for testing

Comment: Ah I see your issue, there are two ways actually for this not really sure whitch one to prefer

Comment: post the solutions ,I will check both and I will let you know

Comment: there is several ways actually it's all depending on how you structure project but post should work else do tell

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I tried the first options and It did not work for me and the second options is to complicated because my app is too much big, I found this library  : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks , it should allow me to create mocks for all my components pipes and directives without having to put it in a module, I will check it out and I will keep you inform

Answer (score 6):

You can read it up on this [ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6050) but the simplest ways should be:

- add a path where you have your testing utilites e.g. "./app/shared/tests/" and in your tsconfig.json add:

  ```
  "exclude": [
    "./app/shared/tests/*.ts"
  ]
  ```

or

- Create a module that is not imported to any other module except Testbed modules using it for testing purposes and include mock, stubs etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ionic Framework with Angular, you need to update the `exclude` section in `tsconfig.app.json` so it lists the files that appear in the error message (or most likely, all similarly named files).

Error:

> Cannot determine the module for class TranslateMockPipe in /src/testing/translate.service.spec.ts! Add TranslateMockPipe to the NgModule to fix it.

tsconfig.app.json

```
...

 "exclude": [
   "src/testing/*.service.spec.ts"
 ]

...
```